# OOP and use of random library to divide footballist between two teams

Tags: python, oop, random

I want to have a class of People and a class of Footballists that inherit from people. I have 22 persons that I must divide between two teams of A and B without overlap. I must also divide people between two classes randomly. I am very new in OOP and here is my code that has overlap. Could you help me?

```
import random
listt=['Hossien','Maziyar','Akbar','Nima','Mahdi','Farhad','Mohammad','Khashayar','Milad','Mostafa','Amin','Saeeid','Poya','Poriya','Reza','Ali','Behzad','Sohiel','Behrooz','Shahrooz','Saman','Mohsen']
#print(listt)
 class Person:

    def __init__(self):
        self.nameList=list()
    
 class Footbalist(Person):
    def __init__(self,team):
        self.team = team

    def get_team(self):
        self.teamA=list(random.sample(listt,11))
        self.teamB=[x for x in listt if x not in self.teamA]


    def printteamA(self):
        print("team A :",self.teamA)
    
    def printteamB(self):
        print("team B :",self.teamB)

A=Footbalist('A')
A.get_team()

B=Footbalist('B')
B.get_team()

A.printteamA()
B.printteamB()
```

Comment: Why does the footbalist inherit from person? You chould only inherit if every footbalist is a person, but it seems to be a container that holds multiple people

Comment: @mousetail, I want to say people is class that has name and foobalist is a class that inherit from people and has name and team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use `super` to inherit `Footbalist` from `Person`. And each `A` and `B` is an instance of `Footbalist`

```
import random
listt=['Hossien','Maziyar','Akbar','Nima','Mahdi','Farhad','Mohammad','Khashayar','Milad','Mostafa','Amin','Saeeid','Poya','Poriya','Reza','Ali','Behzad','Sohiel','Behrooz','Shahrooz','Saman','Mohsen']
#print(listt)
class Person:

    def __init__(self):
        self.nameList=list()

class Footbalist(Person):
    def __init__(self,team_name):
        super().__init__()
        self.team_name = team_name

    def get_team(self, other_team=None):
        if other_team == None:
            self.nameList = list(random.sample(listt, 11))
        else:
            self.nameList=[x for x in listt if x not in other_team.nameList]


    def printteam(self):
        print(f"team {self.team_name}: {self.nameList}")

A=Footbalist('A')
A.get_team()

B=Footbalist('B')
B.get_team(A)

A.printteam()
B.printteam()
```

Comment: I could not understand where you say: def get_team(self, other_team=None):
        if other_team == None: Could you explain it for me?

Comment: It meant having total 22 people to divided, ex. team A and B, each team has 11 people. If the first team is not divided people to, so we need to choose randomly 11 people from 22 people. Else if the first team is devided, we get the rest people to the second team